# Java SFTP server library?

Tags: java, sftp

Is there a Java library that can be used to implement an [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) server?

I'm trying to receive files via SFTP, but I can't seem to find any implementation of an SFTP server.  I've found FTP/SFTP/FTPS *client* libraries, and FTP/FTPS server libraries, but none for a server for SFTP.

To clarify, I'm trying to *receive* files via SFTP.  Not "get" or "put" files from my application to another existing server.

Right now my application lets the users connect to the local linux SFTP server, drop the files, and then my application polls the directory, but I feel that this is a poor implementation; I hate the idea of "polling" directories, but unfortunately they HAVE to use SFTP.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

How to setup an SFTP server using [Apache Mina SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html):

```
public void setupSftpServer(){
    SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
    sshd.setPort(22);
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("hostkey.ser"));

    List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>();
    userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthNone.Factory());
    sshd.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);

    sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());

    List<NamedFactory<Command>> namedFactoryList = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<Command>>();
    namedFactoryList.add(new SftpSubsystem.Factory());
    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(namedFactoryList);

    try {
        sshd.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And that's all.

Comment: This creates a SSH server that most modern clients will refuse to connect to :-( See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690689/no-matching-host-key-type-found-apache-mina-sftp-server

Answer (score 6):

Please notice that SFTP is a not FTP over SSL, nor FTP over SSH. The SFTP server support requires an implementation of SSHD in Java. Your best bet is Apache SSHD,

http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/

I never used the SFTP but I heard it's basic but functional.

Comment: Good point.  The terminology is downright confusing.  So many people think that SFTP is "Secure FTP," or a version of FTP that runs over SSL or SSH, or something (and it's not).  I wish they'd called it something entirely different.

Comment: The link is dead btw

Comment: And FTP over SSL is called FTPS, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP_%C3%BCber_SSL

Comment: Mina SSHD seems to have move to https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing MINA 0.10.1 on Windows with the above and fixed some issues, plus I need better authentication and PK support (still not recommended for production use):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey;

import java.security.KeyFactory;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.DSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import org.apache.sshd.common.NamedFactory;

import org.apache.sshd.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.Command;
import org.apache.sshd.server.command.ScpCommandFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.PasswordAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.PublickeyAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;
import org.apache.sshd.server.sftp.SftpSubsystem;
import org.apache.sshd.server.shell.ProcessShellFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.UserAuth;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.UserAuthPassword;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.UserAuthPublicKey;

import org.apache.sshd.common.KeyExchange;
//import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.DHGEX;
//import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.DHGEX256;
import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.ECDHP256;
import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.ECDHP384;
import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.ECDHP521;
import org.apache.sshd.server.kex.DHG1;

import org.apache.mina.util.Base64;
/*
javac -classpath .;lib/sshd-core-0.10.1.jar;lib/mina-core-2.0.7.jar;lib/waffle-jna.jar;lib/guava-13.0.1.jar;lib/jna-platform-4.0.0.jar;lib/jna-4.0.0.jar SFTPServer.java
java -classpath .;lib/sshd-core-0.10.1.jar;lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.6.jar;lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;lib/mina-core-2.0.7.jar;lib/waffle-jna.jar;lib/guava-13.0.1.jar;lib/jna-platform-4.0.0.jar;lib/jna-4.0.0.jar SFTPServer
*/
public class SFTPServer {
  public void setupSftpServer() throws Exception {

    class AuthorizedKeyEntry {
      private String keyType;
      private String pubKey;

      private byte[] bytes;
      private int pos;
      private PublicKey key = null;

      private int decodeInt() {
        return ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[pos++] & 0xFF);
      }

      private BigInteger decodeBigInt() {
        int len = decodeInt();
        byte[] bigIntBytes = new byte[len];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, pos, bigIntBytes, 0, len);
        pos += len;
        return new BigInteger(bigIntBytes);
      }

      private void decodeType() {
        int len = decodeInt();
        keyType = new String(bytes, pos, len);
        pos += len;
      }

      public PublicKey getPubKey()  {
        return key;
      }

      public void setPubKey(PublicKey key) throws Exception {
        this.key = key;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
        if (key instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
          keyType = "ssh-rsa";
          dos.writeInt(keyType.getBytes().length);
          dos.write(keyType.getBytes());

          RSAPublicKey rsakey = (RSAPublicKey)key;
          BigInteger e = rsakey.getPublicExponent();
          dos.writeInt(e.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(e.toByteArray());
          BigInteger m = rsakey.getModulus();
          dos.writeInt(m.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(m.toByteArray());
        } else if (key instanceof DSAPublicKey) {
          keyType = "ssh-dss";
          dos.writeInt(keyType.getBytes().length);
          dos.write(keyType.getBytes());

          DSAPublicKey dsskey = (DSAPublicKey)key;
          BigInteger p = dsskey.getParams().getP();
          dos.writeInt(p.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(p.toByteArray());
          BigInteger q = dsskey.getParams().getQ();
          dos.writeInt(q.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(q.toByteArray());
          BigInteger g = dsskey.getParams().getG();
          dos.writeInt(g.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(g.toByteArray());
          BigInteger y = dsskey.getY();
          dos.writeInt(y.toByteArray().length);
          dos.write(y.toByteArray());
        } else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown key encoding " + key.getAlgorithm());
        }
        bytes = byteOs.toByteArray();
        this.pubKey = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
      }

      public void setPubKey(String pubKey) throws Exception {
        this.pubKey = pubKey;
        bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(pubKey.getBytes());
        if (bytes == null)
          return;
        decodeType();
        if (keyType.equals("ssh-rsa")) {
          BigInteger e = decodeBigInt();
          BigInteger m = decodeBigInt();
          KeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
          key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
        } else if (keyType.equals("ssh-dss")) {
          BigInteger p = decodeBigInt();
          BigInteger q = decodeBigInt();
          BigInteger g = decodeBigInt();
          BigInteger y = decodeBigInt();
          KeySpec spec = new DSAPublicKeySpec(y, p, q, g);
          key = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA").generatePublic(spec);
        } else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown type " + keyType);
        }
      }
    }

    final SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
    final Map<ServerSession, PublicKey> sessionKeys = new HashMap();

    class AuthorizedKeys extends HashMap<String,AuthorizedKeyEntry> {
      private File file;


      public void load(File file) throws Exception {
        this.file = file;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext())
          decodePublicKey(scanner.next());
        scanner.close();
      }

      public void save() throws Exception {
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (String username : keySet()) {
          AuthorizedKeyEntry entry = get(username);
          w.print(entry.keyType + " " + entry.pubKey + " " + username + "\n");
        }
        w.close();
      }

      public void put(String username, PublicKey key) {
        AuthorizedKeyEntry entry = new AuthorizedKeyEntry();
        try {
          entry.setPubKey(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.put(username,entry);
      }

      private void decodePublicKey(String keyLine) throws Exception {
        AuthorizedKeyEntry entry = new AuthorizedKeyEntry();
        String[] toks = keyLine.split(" ");
        String username = toks[toks.length-1];
        for (String part : toks) {
          if (part.startsWith("AAAA")) {
            entry.setPubKey(part);
            //bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(part.getBytes());
            break;
          }
        }
        super.put(username,entry);
      }
    };

    final AuthorizedKeys authenticUserKeys = new AuthorizedKeys(); // load authorized_keys
    File file = new File("authorized_keys");
    file.createNewFile(); // create if not exists
    authenticUserKeys.load(file);


    sshd.setPort(22);
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("key.ser"));

    sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory(new String[] { "cmd.exe "}));

    sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
      public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
        boolean authentic = false;
        try {
          new waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl().logonUser(username,password);
          authentic = true;
          //authentic = username != null && username.equals(password+password); // obsecurity :)
          if (authentic) {
            PublicKey sessionKey = sessionKeys.get(session);
            if (sessionKey != null)
              authenticUserKeys.put(username, sessionKey); //save entry to authorized_keys
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e);
        }
        return authentic;
      }
    });

    sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new PublickeyAuthenticator() {
      public boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session) {
        sessionKeys.put(session,key);
        return key.equals(authenticUserKeys.get(username).getPubKey());
      }
    });

    sshd.setUserAuthFactories(Arrays.<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>asList(
      new UserAuthPublicKey.Factory()
      ,new UserAuthPassword.Factory()));

    sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());

    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays.<NamedFactory<Command>>asList(
      new SftpSubsystem.Factory()));

    //workaround for apache sshd 10.0+ (putty)
    sshd.setKeyExchangeFactories(Arrays.<NamedFactory<KeyExchange>>asList(
      //new DHGEX256.Factory()
      //,new DHGEX.Factory()
      new ECDHP256.Factory()
      ,new ECDHP384.Factory()
      ,new ECDHP521.Factory()
      ,new DHG1.Factory()));

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          authenticUserKeys.save();
          System.out.println("Stopping");
          sshd.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    System.out.println("Starting");    
    try {
      sshd.start();
      Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new SFTPServer().setupSftpServer();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SSHTools (j2ssh)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools/). It includes a client and server.

However polling a directory isn't that bad an idea - it's probably much more reliable than setting up your own SFTP server using j2ssh. I've lost count of the number of applications I've encountered that do this kind of polling, and it usually works quite well.

Comment: I don't know if it did in the past but it doesn't seem to offer a (n open source) server now.  Perhaps it's been moved to their commercial offering.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness - the [SecureBlackbox](https://www.nsoftware.com/sbb/) library, which we maintain, offers classes to create your own SSH/SFTP server in Java (including Android).

Comment: Link is broken, it is https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/sftpserver/ now. It should also be mentioned that this has a commercial license without public pricing info.

Comment: @MichaelWyraz No, that's a different product. SecureBlackbox is there, alive and kicking. I'll update the link now.

Answer (score -1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javasecureftpd/

Comment: The link you provided is not a java library, it is a standalone product.  Also, it does not appear to use SFTP, but instead FTPS.  Did you read anything about this product, or did you just pick the second link when you googled "java secure ftp"?

Comment: My apologies, I went through a link that said that javasecureftpd was implementing SFTP and I thought it did. Anyway, you don't have to be mean, I was just trying to help you.

Answer (score -2):

i am using jftp http://j-ftp.sourceforge.net/
extract jftp.jar from j-ftp-*.tgz/j-ftp/dist
the only problem - they put apache classes inside there jar (so i have to remove common-httpclient, log4j packages manually to avoid conflicting dependencies)

Comment: Probably because the question was about an SFTP server, not a client.