# In memory/embedded SFTP server for test with private key authentication in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, authentication, ssh, apache-mina

The scenario is that I need to write tests for an application that does SFTP file transfers and I need an **in memory/embedded SFTP server with private key authentication implementation** so that I can test that file transfers run okay with the embedded/ in memory server with private key (.pem) file authentication.

I have raked through the guts of internet the closest I came to was [Apache Mina Server as discussed in this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837948/using-apache-mina-as-a-mock-in-memory-sftp-server-for-unit-testing)

Currently I am using a username and password authentication as below:

```
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setPort(22999);

sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {

    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password,
                                ServerSession session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
});
```

I tried finding a way to implement private key authentication but it seems there is only one authenticator but that is a public key authenticator as below:

```
public void setPublickeyAuthenticator(PublickeyAuthenticator publickeyAuthenticator) {
    this.publickeyAuthenticator = publickeyAuthenticator;
}
```

Is there a way to implement private key authenticator with Apache Mina? or if it's impossible there is there any other mock SFTP server I could use for my testing scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually looking for a **public key authenticator**.

The client/user authenticates with its public key. The server never sees the private key.

---

So you implement the `PublickeyAuthenticator` interface to check if the `PublicKey key` argument of the `authenticate` method matches the public part of the key pair you are using in your client to authenticate.

You can start with `AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator` implementation that uses the [OpenSSH `.ssh/authorized_keys`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files#%7E/.ssh/authorized_keys)-like configuration file.