# SFTP server set user/password in Apache Mina SSHD

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina

I'm using this example, taken from [Java SFTP Server Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076443/java-sftp-server-library):

```
public void setupSftpServer(){
    SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
    sshd.setPort(22);
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("hostkey.ser"));

    List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>();
    userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthNone.Factory());
    sshd.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);

    sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());

    List<NamedFactory<Command>> namedFactoryList = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<Command>>();
    namedFactoryList.add(new SftpSubsystem.Factory());
    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(namedFactoryList);

    try {
        sshd.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I need to set user login and pw for SFTP server. How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: did you have any luck? It lacks documentation. Please help me share your experience.

Comment: No luck, still waiting for response.

Comment: i created an answer, maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694108/apache-mina-sshd-problems-with-authentication-method-when-connecting-to-server/21553897#21553897

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `new UserAuthNone.Factory()` to `new UserAuthPassword.Factory()` and then implement and register `PasswordAuthenticator` object. Its `authenticate` method should return `true` for valid username and password parameters.

```
List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>();
userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthPassword.Factory());
sshd.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);

sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
        return "tomek".equals(username) && "123".equals(password);
    }
});
```