# SFTP server multiple user authentication

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, ftp-server

I am trying to extend the user authentication example, which is also presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925347/sftp-server-set-user-password-in-apache-mina-sshd), so that multiple users can login to the server. I would also like to assign a different home directory for each user. So far, I haven't been able to find any such utility provided by the [Apache SSHD API](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html), so I have tried the following workaround, by using the utilities provided by the [Apache FtpServer](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html).

What I attempt to do is:

1. create a UserManager object to manage a list of users and store their information in a property file, in a way similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969097/writing-a-java-ftp-server)
2. create a PasswordAuthenticator that makes use of the UserManager in its *authenticate* method, as follows:

   ```
   public class MyPasswordAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticator {

       private UserManager userManager;

       public MyPasswordAuthenticator(){
           this.userManager=null;
       }

       public MyPasswordAuthenticator(UserManager manager) {
           this.userManager=manager;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) throws PasswordChangeRequiredException {
           if (this.userManager==null) return false;
           User usr=null;
           try {
               usr = userManager.getUserByName(username);
           } catch (FtpException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if (usr==null) return false;
           else{       
               String pass=usr.getPassword();
               return password.equals(pass);
           }
       }


   }
   ```

However, the `usr.getPassword()` returns null, even though a) the password fields in the property file do have values b) I have checked the functions `getName()` and `getHomeDirectory()` and they return their respective String values.

My question is, why does this happen and what should be done to fix this?

Comment: There's no actual implementation of `PasswordAuthenticator` for multi-user server in Apache SSHD. You are supposed to implement your own. It's not a workaround. It's a part of the implementation.

Comment: So your actual question is, why the your implementation of the `UserManager` interface is not working. But didn't show us anything about its implementation.

Comment: You are actually asking two completely unrelated questions. Split them in two posts. Or decide which of them you want to ask.

Comment: You are correct about the implementation, I am using the `PropertiesUserManager`. I have located the problem, this class loads all properties of a `User` in its `getUserByName` function, except from its password. I'll try to work it out, thanks.

Comment: I have found a way to make it work, it is:


`usr = this.userManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthentication(username, password));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to make it work, it is:

```
usr = this.userManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthentication(username, password));
```