# Embedded SFTP server in java code

Tags: java, testing, apache-camel, sftp

I need to test Apache camel SFTP consumer. Is there a way to run an embedded SFTP server to test my code in dev environment? Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076443/java-sftp-server-library?rq=1 comes with a full Apache Mina SSHD example

Comment: I'd second Mina to be the best answer for you. I don't know of another way to run an embedded server. Another option would be to look for a mock FTP server, such as the one detialed here: https://itsiastic.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/how-to-create-a-java-ftp-server-mock/

Comment: Thanks Guys! Apache Mina looks promising at least for the testing I need to perform. Can you also point me to correct direction for how I can generate keys for authentication on this embedded server?

Answer (score 2):

Once I had a similiar problem and therefore wrote a JUnit 4 rule that runs an SFTP server during your test. It is called [Fake SFTP Server Rule](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-rule) and uses Apache Mina SSHD internally. Here is an example of a test using that rule:

```
public class SomeTest {
    @Rule
    public final FakeSftpServerRule sftpServer = new FakeSftpServerRule();

    @Test
    public void testTextFile() {
        //code that uploads the file

        String fileContent = sftpServer.getFileContent("/directory/file.txt", UTF_8);

        //verify content
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have plans to support JUNIT5?

Comment: @Stefan Birken, the example of the code above produce: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download file because test has not been started or is already finished (Junit 4.12 + java 11)

Comment: I don't want to do inside @Test method, I wanted to do in automation testing server I need to make it up, how I can achieve that?

Comment: I worked with your fake sftp server a lot, thank you! now I have to add support to RSA key, do you support?